# How to modify a Customer Refund in an After Submit User Event

Tags: netsuite

After a new Customer Refund record is saved (After Submit user event) I need to communicate with an external web service and then update 2 fields in the record. When this code is executed to load the Customer Refund

```
var o = nlapiLoadRecord("customerrefund", 1906);
```

This error message is returned:

```
INVALID_TRANS_TYP
Transaction type specified is incorrect.
```

I found a list of supported records in the "Chapter 60 SuiteScript Supported Records" of [SuiteScript Developer & Reference Guide](https://system.netsuite.com/core/media/media.nl?id=5732122&c=NLCORP&h=5fca4bf5dd825a28ab41&_xt=.pdf&addrcountry=US) which says the Customer Refund is only available in a server side script.

How should I go about updating the Customer Refund record?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without seeing more code, it looks ok.  I would double check that the internalId of 1906 is correct.

Also, if you're just submitting two fields, I would use nlapiSubmitField(), this will take less governance points and be quicker for NetSuite rather than nlapiLoadRecord / nlapiSubmitRecord.

Comment: It ends up I was in the debugger when I was having problems with the "Transaction type specified is incorrect.", it works great in the user event. Thanks for the tip of using nlapiSubmitField(), I haven't come across that api call yet.

Comment: @RussPetersen  Just a note, even script record deployment logs should be not in DEBUG mode.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks correct, if you are updating the current record I would recommend using below code to avoid incorrect `internalid`:

```
var o = nlapiLoadRecord("customerrefund", nlapiGetRecordId());
```

Also, I would recommend that if you need to update the fields, consider using `before submit` user event script on customer refund and you can update the fields using `nlapiSetFieldValue(FIELD_ID, FIELD_VALUE)`. No need to submit the record in case of before submit.

Comment: Agree with this; when you are modifying the exact record being submitted, you should try to use `Before Submit` instead of `After Submit`; otherwise, this record type will be submitted to the database twice *every time it is saved*. Sometimes, it is unavoidable, but you absolutely want to limit the scenarios when this happens as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

If your script is deployed in the customer refund record, you can also do nlapiGetRecordType().